# Optimize brute force algorithm in python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-itertools, brute-force

I was trying to implement a simple brute force approach in python to search for a string pattern using a built-in library functions.Here is the code

```
from itertools import product
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import numpy as np

chars=np.array(['a','b','c','d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'])
password='cgbjfifac'
min_length=1
max_length=9

def brute_force():
    for length in range(min_length, max_length + 1):
        for p in product(chars, repeat=length):
            guess = ''.join(p)
            if guess == password:
                return guess
```

It took about **87 seconds** on a dual core Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.30GHz machine.

I already tried **multiprocessing** approach using standard library in python (ie. using **pool and map** methods); but it did not offer any speed up.

How can we further improve the performance of this method.
(Ideally the input will have length >= 10)

Reference: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47952987/how-to-make-all-of-the-permutations-of-a-password-for-brute-force)

Answer (score 1):

I took out numpy and dropped the "".join ,  sped up by ~ x3.

```
from itertools import product
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

start_time = time.time()

chars=['a','b','c','d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
password=tuple('cgbjfifac')
min_length=1
max_length=9

def brute_force():
    for length in range(min_length, max_length + 1):
        for p in product(chars, repeat=length):
            if p == password:
                return p



brute_force()

print(time.time()-start_time)
```

Comment: Thanks, now it reduced to 30 s.. Did you try multiprocessing approach ???

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly better version of the code, using multiprocessing ...

```
from itertools import product
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time


chars=['a','b','c','d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
password=tuple('cgbjfifac')
min_length=1
max_length=9

def parallel_brute_force(length):
        for p in product(chars, repeat=length):
            if p == password:
                return p

tick=time.time()

with multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as p:
       for v in p.imap_unordered(parallel_brute_force, range(min_length, max_length + 1):
           result=v


print("Time :" + str(time.time()-tick) + " s")
print(result)
```

The time reduced from 23s to 17s on 4 core 2.0GHz machine .. **1.3x** improvement !!!

Refs :-

1. [Python: Differences between imap/imap_unordered and map/map_async](https://guangyuwu.wordpress.com/2018/01/12/python-differences-between-imap-imap_unordered-and-map-map_async/)
2. [Rosettacode: Parallel Brute Force](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Parallel_Brute_Force#Python)